# Why does getchar() not work right?

Tags: c, cygwin

Today, I wrote a simple piece of code that uses  `getchar()` to count the characters you input. But when I compile it on Cygwin, it does not work. It always prints 0, but I never input anything or I can't input any characters it prints 0.

However, if I compile it with VC++6.0, it works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 long nc;

 nc = 0;
 while(getchar() != EOF)
    ++nc;
 printf("The total of characters you inputed is %ld.\n", nc);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you using to compile on cygwin? I have cygwin and use VC to compile and this works fine.

Comment: Your exact code works perfectly for me in Cygwin (compiling with GCC). You do have to hit control-D to send an EOF.

Comment: How *exactly* are you running the program? What happens when you run `echo hello | ./your_program` from a Cygwin bash shell prompt?     What if you type just `./your_program`, then `hello`, then Enter, then Control-D?

Comment: I am sorry, but i can not post the image about the problem. This code file named nc.c.Then I complier it on Cygwin with this command'gcc nc.c',and it not prints any errors so I run it with './a' and clik the enter.But it prints 0.

Comment: @Zsm0107: I wasn't asking for an image.  Please try the commands I suggested in my previous comment, and tell us what the result was.  (Your program works correctly for me on Cygwin.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: I'm so sorry to too late to write back. When I run echo hello | ./nc,then click enter. It prints The total of characters you inputed is 6. But when I just run ./nc hello then clik enter It prints The total of characters you inputed is 0. My cygwin is 1.7.9 version. I do not know why it does not work. However , I run it with cmd.exe, it work .

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I just run it with ./nc on my Cygwin then clik enter but 'it prints The total of characters you inputed is 0'.I just can not input other characters.

Comment: @hmjd: I command like this: gcc nc.c -o nc; then clik enter. No errors prints. Then I run it: ./nc then clik enter,it prints The total of characters you inputed is 0'.but i can not input other characters .

Comment: @Zsm0107: If you run `./nc hello`, it passes `"hello"` to the command as an argument, *not* as input.  Type `./nc`, then **Enter**, then `hello`, then **Enter**, then **Control-D**.  (In any case, we know that your program is able to read and count characters from its standard input; the problem is in your environment, *not* in your C code.)

Comment: @Zsm0107: I wonder if your tty settings might be messed up.  What if you type **Control-J** or **Control-M** instead of **Enter**?  Also, the `wc` command does something similar to what your program does; do you have the same problem if you use `wc` instead of `./nc`?  (I'm grasping at straws.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks for the previous comment. I learn something. But try the next comement, it does not work. Also i try wc instead of ./nc, but I do not know what about the wc. When using wc clik enter then zsm the Control-D it prints 1 1 4. but I do not konw that.

Comment: @Zsm0107: `wc` is working correctly when reading from the keyboard, your program works correctly when reading from a pipe (`echo hello | ./nc`), but `./nc` by itself immediately terminates.  I'm running out of ideas.  Are you 100% sure the code you posted is exactly the program you're running?  If you modify the program (have it print `"hello"`), recompile it, and run it, does it print the new message *and* print 0?  The point is that you might somehow not be running the code you think you're running; I've made that kind of mistake myself.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: I am sure the code i posted is exactly the program I am runnig. I review it again and again. There is a [site](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2000-09/msg00880.html) ,that Chritian Jonassen. Maybe it is right. -:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This email thread](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2000-09/msg00880.html) talks about a bug that sounds much like yours, but I can't see that there are any follow-ups to it.

I would be interested to know what happened when you try

`while(getc(stdin) != EOF)`

and if that doesn't work, try 
`while(fgetc(stdin) != EOF)`

*All of them should work*, though [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/getc.html) page suggests there could be implementation differences between these functions.

Another thing you could try is to print the ASCII value of what you get:

`printf("%d\n",(int)getchar());`

Also, try piping output from a file instead of typing it in the console. Create a file `input.txt`, put some characters in it, and do

`cat input.txt | ./program`

EDIT: You write running cat and piping it works. I would say simply update your Cygwin version. You have encountered a bug. Get the newest versions of Cygwin and the compiler, and you should be good to go. Another option is to use [scanf](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_016.htm).

Comment: while(getc(stdin) != EOF) and wihle(fgetc(stdin) != EOF) also don't work. And "printf("%d\n",(int)getchar());" prints '-1'.But I curios about the cat input.txt | ./a .It runs well. But I can't understand it,why it can run well.

Comment: Update your tools. :) Also, try running the program using cmd.exe instead of the Cygwin shell. Does that work?

Comment: My Cygwin is [link](http://www.cygwin.com/),So i think it is the latest version but I use cmd.exe to run it.It work correctly.

Comment: @Chritian Jonassen: "The most recent version of the Cygwin DLL is 1.7.9-1. Install it by running setup.exe." this one. i am sorry to not post clearly.

Comment: When I compile it with gcc version 4.5.3 (GCC) and run it in the Cygwin terminal mintty 1.0.3, the program works as it should.

Comment: @Chritian Jonassen: May I uncorrecty install  Cygwin? I try this way. mintty-> gcc nc.c -o nc -> ./nc then clik enter.But it prints 0. when i try to use this command: cat input.txt | ./nc . it works. Thank you.

Comment: I just installed Cygwin that  selected the Dev items ,but others were defaulted.So I guess i might it not correctly.